# Why type casting is required while using itrerator object in the while loop?

Tags: java, collections

I am learning java right now. While writing code for traversing `ArrayList` using `Iterator` I have to use the class name before using the iterator's object with `next()` function. Can anybody help me with this?

```
import java.util.*;

public class arraylistwithuserdefinedclass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        ArrayList<UserId> details=new ArrayList<UserId>();
        UserId a=  new UserId(22,"gurmeet");    
        UserId b=  new UserId(24,"sukhmeet");
        details.add(a);
        details.add(b);
        Iterator itr = details.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext()) {    
            UserId ui = (UserId) itr.next();
            System.out.println(ui.age +" " + "" + ui.name) ;
        }
    }       
}

class UserId {
    int age;
    String name;
    UserId(int a, String b) {
        age=a;
        name=b;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make your Iterator `UserId` type (specify the type), ie

```
Iterator<UserId> itr = details.iterator();
```

Because if you don't specify the type, how will it understand what to return. So for generalized purpose it will return Object type and thats why downcasting is required.

Comment: what is downcasting?

Comment: Are you familiar with narrowing and widening of primitive data types in Java

Comment: no i am not familiar with it

Comment: **Casting**   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23414090/what-is-the-difference-between-up-casting-and-down-casting-with-respect-to-class

Comment: **Widening&NArrowing** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16781649/real-world-application-of-widening-narrowing-conversion

Comment: thanks for helping me

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify the generic type for the Iterator because without this type the Iterator holds type Object :

```
Iterator itr = details.iterator();// This holds type Object.
```

for that it is required to cast every Object.

---

another [reference](http://www.leepoint.net/data/collections/iterators.html) :

> **it.next()** Returns the next object. If a generic list is being accessed, the iterator will return something of the list's type.
>   Pre-generic Java iterators always returned type Object, so a downcast
>   was usually required.

---

it is not required if you set the type for the Iterator :

```
Iterator<UserId> itr = details.iterator();
//         ^^--------------------------
```

So you can use without casting :

```
while (itr.hasNext()) {
    UserId ui = itr.next();
//-------------^
```

Comment: if i use it without casting then it shows me an error and i cant compile my code

Comment: you have to use `Iterator<UserId>` like i already mentioned instead of just `Iterator` @GURMEETSINGH

Comment: check my edit @GURMEETSINGH you will understand more now

Comment: thanks for clearing my concept.

Answer (score 1):

Your iterator is declared raw, that is the reason why you need to cast, do instead declare the iterator as a ***UserId*** doing  `Iterator<UserId>`

```
Iterator<UserId> itr = details.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()) {
        ...
        UserId ui = (UserId)
```

Comment: yes i am getting this warning ** Iterator is a raw type. References to generic type Iterator<E> should be parameterized** . but what does raw means here.

Comment: and do tell me how to remove this problem.

Comment: raw means it has no type

Comment: is right there in the answer... do  Iterator<UserId> instead of  Iterator

Comment: raw means you haven't provided a type parameter. Think of them as a dynamic type.

Comment: thanks for your help.